# Reading struct from NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I am working on a payment processor class right now and I have hit a roadblock. I am using the FastSpring e-commerce service and they have a nice set of tools, but I am stuck on one thing.

For PayPal IPN, to get the person's first name (this is in C#/ASP code) I would do this:

```
base.Context.Request.Params["first_name"]
```

With FastSpring, they seem to store the information within a structure, as seen here in "customer": http://nvsx.net/i/c2252.png

How would I modify my code to properly create that structure from the HTTP post context?

**Updates:**

NameValueCollection keys: http://pastie.org/1346312

Customer Key Value: `{0} --> {1}Customercom.brightmarket.api.variable.v1.contact.ContactVariable@175d7aa`

Comment: Well they don't make their API publicly available so at best guess I would say either you make a HTTP POST request with application/json and JSON formatted content or its a HTTP POST request with an XML body to a web service.  If you can find a public link to their API I could help a bit more.

Comment: They send their post data to my script just fine. I just need to find a way to interpret it.. But here is that page: https://springboard.fastspring.com/assist/doc/variable.xml?name=Order&package=v1

Comment: Posting a sanitized data sample would help immensely.

Comment: I tried to create a complete dump of the context, but all I could generate was the list of keys for the NameValueCollection: http://pastie.org/1346312

Comment: @Eaton: `sb.AppendLine("{0} --> {1}", str, Context.Request.Params[str]);`  Also, you can edit your question -- please post content related to your question in the question itself instead of using pastebins.

Comment: Updated with results from that code. (Had to modify it to get it to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's already a proper object, no? You should just have to cast it.

Have you tried something like

```
var contact = (ContactVariable)Context.Request.Params[str];
```

and then using the members of the contact variable?

Comment: C# doesn't allow casting strings to structures. ):

Comment: What you have there is either not a string, or it's an object reference on their end that they converted to a string -- and that's just wrong.  Are you the one sending this data to your server, or are they?  Because there's nothing at all you can parse from that string.

Comment: They are sending the data to my script. And yeah, not completely sure, they don't provide any C# examples for parsing their post data.

Comment: Is your script being called as POST or GET?  If it's GET, perhaps the data is being sent in the entity body?

Comment: Post. I have the option of using Get in my control panel on FastSpring, though.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what to tell you except to display all of the values and start looking at stuff and try to find something that contains the data you're after.

Comment: I will send in a support ticket on their site. Thank you for the help, I will mark this as the answer since you helped the most.

Comment: @Eaton: Thanks, good luck with the project.  I'll be interested to hear what the solution is.